# Are there ways to change the format of SQL output in VSCode?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

Specifically, I've noticed a difference between SSMS and VSCode, when resizing a column of the output results. SSMS displays the column contents bounded by the resized width before you drop your mouse drag to complete the resize, while VSCode does not. Is there a way to get more user-friendly SQL results in VSCode?

I've tried briefly searching for popular sql vs extensions. Is this something which can be achieved with basic VSCode settings instead?

I'm assuming this decision was intentionally made for a performance trade-off, but I'm hoping this is something that either is currently, or will become a configurable option if VSCode will one day replace SSMS.

Comment: What does `before you drop to commit the changes` mean? There are no changes in query results that could get committed. The equivalent (in fact, the successor) to SSMS is Azure Data Studio, not VS Code anyway.

Comment: I've reworded to remove the extension request, and edited to remove the commit changes language. By "commit changes", I was just referring to releasing your mouse drag event while resizing a column width within VSCode vs SSMS.